# NSIS Displays accented letters wrong

Tags: nsis

I am trying to create a simple installer using NSIS. Included in the installer, is the license, a default MIT-license. The only problem is that my name (which is included in the license) contains an `é`, which is displayed in the installer as `Ã©`. How can I fix this? I already tried `Unicode True` in the `.nsi`-file.

Answer (score 1):

Store your license file as UTF-8 with a BOM or UTF-16LE with a BOM:

```
!tempfile "${EXAMPLELICENSE}" ; Create license on the fly for this example
!appendfile /CHARSET=UTF8SIG "${EXAMPLELICENSE}" "Héllo World$\nFrom ${U+2115}SIS$\n"
LicenseData "${EXAMPLELICENSE}"
!delfile "${EXAMPLELICENSE}"

Page License
Page InstFiles

Section
SectionEnd
```